# Data Bind Asp .Net Drop Down List SelectedValue to Page Property

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, code-behind

I have a property in my Page

```
Public Property Status as String
```

I set up the status list manually by calling

```
list.Items.Add(New ListItem("Open", "Open"))
```

and then I call

```
list.DataBind()
```

On my page I want to set the selected value to the value in that property and I want the value in that property to contain the value of the list on each post back.

I tried `SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Status") %>'` but I get the following error:

> Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be
>   used in the context of a data bound control.

Is there something I am missing?  The end goal is to have the state of the DropDownList persisted to the Page property between post backs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the selected value of dropdownlist by

```
status=DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
```

In order to get selected value after each postback,you need to add event in your dropdownlist  `onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"` and in that event you can get selected value as follows.

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            status=DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
        }
```

you can persist the value of your status property by creating a view state as follows(in c#)

```
public string status
        {

     get
            {
                if (ViewState["status"] != null)
                    return ViewState["status"].ToString();
                else
                    return null;
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["status"] = value;
            }

        }
```

Comment: This does not work because if another control triggers a post back I loose the value in Status

Answer (score 0):

The server control has viewstate  that persist the value of the control between postbacks automatically as long as you don't set the viewstate property of a control to false.

Second thing is you dont need to call it the DataBind() function in your case.

Comment: I am trying to persist the value to a Page property.

Comment: if(Page.IsPostback){Status = dropdownlist1.selectedValue; }

Comment: I want it to happen automatically.  I assumed Bind would do this?  I don't want to call list.SelectedValue